# Clear server's cached files

Tags: php, apache, caching, server

If I load up a file to my server (an apache) via FTP, the file is correctly uploadet, but when I open it in any browser, an older version of that file is shown (btw, it's a php file). I think, resetting the servers cache will solve the problem, but how can I do this?

Can I use php for this? I've found somethin called htcacheclear in the web, but I don't understand. how to use it. The main problem is, that I have no access to a Terminal or Console, that would be a kind of easy...

Any solution?

Comment: First thing is to check, is the file you are modifying, is actually the one you are visiting? Servers don't usually cache these files out of the box. You will need specialized softwares to actually achieve it.

Comment: @LionelChan I've already checked this...

Comment: how old the version of the file is? is it one step behind, of it's totally old? I think you might even upload to different directory, or something. Also make sure the server response is not cached with headers, and you are getting it fresh in the browser, clean browsers cache.

Comment: you sure it's the server caching it, and not your client? shift-F5 in your browser forces a "fresh" fetch.

Comment: I've tried this with several browsers, all cache-cleared, nothing changed. Im 100% sure it's the servers cache

Answer (score 1):

1) Simply changing the file name serve new files.

**OR**

2) You can use Apache httpd.conf to do this.
   Enable mod_headers.so module from httpd.conf and apply those settings at the end of file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    <FilesMatch "!.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|php)$">
        ExpiresACtive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
        Header unset Cookie
        Header unset Set-Cookie
        php_value session.cookie_domain example.com
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|woff)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
        Header unset Cookie
        Header unset Set-Cookie
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
        #ExpiresDefault A29030400
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
        #Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
        ExpiresDefault A29030400
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
        Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
    Header unset Pragma
    FileETag None
    Header unset ETag
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your first solution is the thing I already use, but it's annoing me. I'll try the second one, but where should I place this file and what do you mean with 'apply the settings at the end of the file'?

Comment: If your environment is windows then this file resides in the xampp\apache\conf.

Comment: Yes, but in my localhost it works. Where should I place the file on the apache server? in the root dir?

Comment: Sometimes restarting your Apache server attaches new ETag to files and it clear the cache.

Comment: That doesn't worked for me and renaming the file is no option here.

Comment: Ok. In detail. Which OS you are using? and where is your installation path of the PHP/Apache?

Comment: As I said it's not my server and I have no access to the file system or an terminal, but it's an apache server on Ubuntu 14.04. It seems tobe a problem with the servers cache, in my localhost everything works fine and the file is uploaded via FTP correctly...

Comment: Then leave it. There is nothing you can do with this. I had same problems with the Google App Engine. It's Paas architecture only and can't give you access to the server at all. Only changing file names will work in this case. Most of the static content served through CDN. And there is limitation to clear cache from the  CDN.

Comment: Hmm, I hope some updates causing the server to restart will fix the problem some time